# Fatal error encountered during command execution. -- aspx VB - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

i'm try to iterate more then one INSERT in my db whit ASPX/VB i take the value from a gridview:

```
            For Each row As GridViewRow In gv_membri.Rows
                Dim ChkBoxRows As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("cb_membri"), CheckBox)
                If ChkBoxRows.Checked Then
                    Dim select_udp_membri As New MySqlParameter("@udp_membri", MySqlDbType.Int16, 11)

                    select_udp_membri.Value = CInt(row.Cells(1).Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(select_udp_membri)
                    con.Open()
                    Try

                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        lblerr0.Text = "INSERT udp_user ERROR: " + ex.Message

                        Exit For
                    End Try
                    cmd1.Parameters.Clear()
                    con.Close()
                End If
            Next
```

the first time it take the value form the gridview's checkbox and it work fine but at the second time return me this error: 
Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand why you open and close the connection every time. also could you show the cmd1

Comment: As mentioned by @nbk, opening and closing that connection on every loop iteration might be part of your problem.  Perhaps move that outside your loop.  Apart from that, can you give use the command text for cmd1

Comment: It's also wrong to keep adding and removing the command parameter. You should be adding the parameter once and then setting its `Value` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the comments are pointing towards the following. The Using...End Using block makes sure the database objects are closed and disposed.

```
Protected Sub OPCode()
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your connection String"),
            cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("Insert Into ??? (???) Values (@udp_membri);", con)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@udp_membri", MySqlDbType.Int16, 11)
        con.Open()
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim ChkBoxRows As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("cb_membri"), CheckBox)
            If ChkBoxRows.Checked Then
                cmd1.Parameters("@udp_membri").Value = CInt(row.Cells(1).Text)
                Try
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    lblerr0.Text = "INSERT udp_user ERROR: " + ex.Message
                    Exit For
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```